# "LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode." When Rotating a Table

Tags: tables, xetex, rotating, sidewaystable, ctex

I wanted to rotate my table using `sidewaystable` in LaTeX, but it turned out to be wrong with the error message `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`, whose location is marked with `%`'s below.

```
% !TEX program  = xelatex

\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\RequirePackage{ctex}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{table} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \caption{单次放行车辆$n$与期望值的关系}\label{tab:001} \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            $n$(辆) & $E(\frac{1}{\mu})$\\
            \midrule[1pt]
            1 & 31.60 \\
            2 & 16.80 \\
            3 & 11.87 \\
            4 & 9.40 \\
            5 & 7.92 \\
            6 & 6.93 \\
            7 & 6.23 \\
            8 & 5.70 \\
            9 & 5.29 \\
            10 & 4.96 \\
            11 & 4.69 \\
            12 & 4.47 \\
            13 & 4.28 \\
            14 & 4.11 \\
            15 & 3.97 \\
            \bottomrule[1.5pt]
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

How can I possibly fix that problem in the easiest way?

Comment: Don't use `table` in the `sidewaystable` environment, just remove that inner environment and it should work (untested)

Comment: `sidewaystable` replaces `table` not wraps around it.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

(posting this as an answer so that this query can be treated as having been answered)

The immediate step to take -- already noted by skillmon and David Carlisle -- is to get rid of (or comment out) the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` statements: The `sidewaystable` environment is not a wrapper around a `table` environment but, instead, a drop-in replacement.

In addition, you may want to enhance the visual appeal of the table by, say, aligning the numbers in both columns on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers. This can be done easily with the help of the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.

A separate issue: I noticed that your override the default widths of the rules produced by `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`. If you do this for all of your tables, it's a good idea to modify the values of length parameters `\heavyrulewidth` and `\lightrulewidth` in the preamble -- and declutter the code in the various `tabular` environments in the body of the text.

[image]

```
% !TEX program  = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% New instructions:
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{1.5pt}  % default: 0.08em
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.0pt}  % default: 0.05em
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional: create some whitespace below the caption

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
%%%% \begin{table} %%%%%%%%%%%  %% not needed (actually: counterproductive!)
    \caption{单次放行车辆$n$与期望值的关系}
    \label{tab:001} 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=2.2] @{}}
            \toprule
            {$n$\,(辆)} & {$E(1/\mu)$}\\
            \midrule
             1 & 31.60 \\
             2 & 16.80 \\
             3 & 11.87 \\
             4 &  9.40 \\
             5 &  7.92 \\
             6 &  6.93 \\
             7 &  6.23 \\
             8 &  5.70 \\
             9 &  5.29 \\
            10 &  4.96 \\
            11 &  4.69 \\
            12 &  4.47 \\
            13 &  4.28 \\
            14 &  4.11 \\
            15 &  3.97 \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
%%%% \end{table} %%%%%%%%%%%  %% not needed
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```